# Open multiple tab creating function in controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

my controller function is :-

```
vm.selectSales = function () {
        var url = "";
        if ($scope.selection.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.selection.length; i < len; i++) {
             url=($state.href('work-area', { 'saleId': $scope.selection[i] ;
              window.open(data, '_blank');
             $window.location.reload();
        }}};
```

According to this, i want to open multiple tab, but only one tab is open. Please suggest me a way to open multiple tab with different sale id.

Comment: its data or url    window.open(data, '_blank');

Comment: yes it is 'url' , by type mistake written as 'data'....

Answer (score 2):

After searched a lot i found that code is fine, i.e. below code work perfectly :-

```
 vm.selectSales = function () {
        var url = "";
        if ($scope.selection.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, len = $scope.selection.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = ($state.href('work-area', { 'saleId': $scope.selection[i] }));
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            }}
      };
```

But it is not work due to chrome popups setting its not work.

Now, to work with this code, i need to change my chrome setting :-
Click on Setting----->Advanced Setting----->Content Settings----->allow all sites to show popups.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you didn't close $state.href's second parameter.

Also, ¿why are you doing a location.reload inside the for? It will reload the main page on execution, making it impossible for you to do what you want.

If window.open(url, '_blank') really opens a tab, you could give this a go:

```
vm.selectSales = function () {
        var url = "";
        if ($scope.selection.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.selection.length; i < len; i++) {
             url=($state.href('work-area', { 'saleId': $scope.selection[i]};
              window.open(data, '_blank');
        }
      $window.location.reload();
      }
    };
```

Having serious doubts on the location reload though .

Comment: relaod function reloads the current page, however window.open() can open only one tab.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
            } Opens three tabs for me